# how to start a Commute trip in nokia drive (here drive+)?

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, here

I create a new commute, set the time and save it. 
then when I go I donøt know how to activate it. If I go in and select it I only have the option to delete it or edit it.

Is it suppose to start automatically when it feels the car is moving? or am I doing somethign wrong that does not let it start?

Comment: Have you tried leaving the app open while to drive?

Comment: mmm I kind of came to the same conclusion reading the manual, but I didn't try it as I thought it could not be possible... I'll try it today

Comment: it did not work. the only way to make a commute start seems like deleting it and recreating it, and then the first time it's created it will start, but never again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is approximately an hour, I have "My Commute" as a Live Tile.

There are a few settings you may need to check:

1. In Here Drive scroll down to Settings
2. Select "My Commute"
3. Make Sure "My Commute" is on.
4. To create a live tile of your commute (provided you have created one) click "Pin to start" (it is in text and hard to see).
5. Now you can start your commute anytime from your live tile, it will also show you how long it will take to you to drive there around an hour before your start time.

Also to start your commute:

1. Open Here Drive
2. Click My Commute
3. Swipe to the side to show a single commute page instead of the all commutes page.
4. Tap the commute to begin driving!

Finally, if the tile does not update, or you are still having problems check your background tasks settings:

1. Open Phone Settings
2. Swipe sideways to applications
3. Click background tasks
4. Find Here Drive
5. Check the box "Turn Background tasks back on.."
6. Open Here Drive

Hope this solves any problems you have been having :)

Answer (score 4):

If you add your commute route you specify a time for the commute.
If you start Here drive+ at this time you will have a tile for this commute as shown in the screenshot (here the tile with 43 min/Home)
[image: screenshot]

And here is a screenshot if your are not in a timeslot for an saved route. If you click on emphasized tile you will first see your saved route to home. If you swipe left you will find all saved routes.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: How exact do I have to be to turn it on at the right time? I tried many time but it just never appeared.

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark Just updatet my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: I guess what the previus person was trying to ask which I still find confusing is if you setup a commute, it is only active to be used for a time range. Exactly how close to your "normal" commute time do you have to be? I have a flexible schedule, so I cannot really use this because even though I set up my commute for 7am, I could leave between 5:30am and 8am. I can rarely use the commute feature because of this, although it would be useful.

Comment: yes I also had the same problem.